# Given a 'java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException' is it possible to determine column('s) in error

Tags: java, sql, jpa, unique-constraint

Given I have an exception of type 'java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException'

Is it possible to programmatically determine the column (or columns) in error? I ask this because I would like to map the error back to the client's data model to indicate field in error (for example a violation of a unique key).

For example given a duplicate value is attempted to be inserted on a table, the 'java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException' exception would be thrown with the following message:

> The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key
>   value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified
>   by 'INDEX_NAME' defined on 'COLUMN_NAME'.

Having the error type, and fields in error would allow the client to nicely indicate which input was in error, and the error message.
I guess I could try passing the error message, to get the info that I need (obviously that would not be a nice solution.)

Does anyone know of a good way to extract the column in error from the exception?

Answer (score 2):

Quite a bit of this is going to be vendor specific. You can learn a lot from the [sql error code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode%28%29). But as the javadoc noted, the value is vendor specific. Spring has a [utility](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.1.5/api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.html) which is able to translate these codes (with support for many vendors) into a more specific exception hierarchy. In the case of a constraint violation you would likely get a DataIntegrityViolationException, but that still would not provide explicit access to the index name being violated. The message, however, likely would include the index name.