# Is there a way to get "java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException" from Microsoft SQL JDBC driver?

Tags: java, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I have noticed that MS SQL JDBC driver throws

```
"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException"
```

for constraint violation issues. Is there a way to get subtype of

```
"java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException"
```

from the driver for  a constraint violation? may be using a different driver?

Comment: You don't "get" an exception, you hit one when something goes wrong.  In any case, the JBDC JAR you are currently using should have all exceptions which its code ever throws.

Comment: In my case I expect this to happen under high concurrency. So I'm writing a recovery mechanism to prevent database being inconsistent. I just need a driver which throws an exception in the type of "java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException" for this issue. But current driver throws generic "SQLServerException" which makes me check the error message to identify the constraint violation.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600993/given-a-java-sql-sqlintegrityconstraintviolationexception-is-it-possible-to-de

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see the JDBC API you're calling to see if the Microsoft JDBC implementation throws `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`. As [Tim B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) mentioned above, you can't force a method to throw an exception if it wasn't coded to do so. Check the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.html).

> Please consult your driver vendor documentation for the **vendor-specified** conditions for which this Exception may be thrown.